# Protecting software language question?

Tags: discussion

I think it might be time to table the Fortran question. It's gathered several good answers, and I'm worried it might degrade into a "what is my favorite language" debate - if it hasn't already.

(Yes, I'm not entirely sure I should have kept in to answer.)

Comment: I can protect it, but want to get a bit of feedback before doing so.

Comment: I also don't want to look like I'm protecting a question once I got points. (I don't really need them.)

Comment: I am open to suggestions about this, too.  I was concerned in the beginning that it would turn discussion-y and it's starting to look that way.  It has been further victimized by the "Hot Questions" list phenomenon as well.

Comment: I don't think anyone would think you had ulterior motives had you protected it, though

Comment: I went ahead and protected it. I was thinking about that already yesterday and since you raised that here again I thought I just go ahead. This is a question which will attract people to just state opinions and the protection can be lifted.

Comment: Thanks @Martin!  I think that was the right call.